# Axios GET request to the discord API gives a 403 forbidden response, but works in Postman

Tags: javascript, rest, axios, postman, discord

I am using axios to make a HTTP GET request to the discords API on my local environment.

I am using the below code:

```
axios.get('https://discord.com/api/channels/735303230694621228', {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bot ' + botToken,
    },
  }).then((data) => {
    res = data.response
  })
```

The Bot is the owner of channel id: 735303230694621228 and has all the correct permissions.

**Actual Result:**

The preflight request (OPTIONS) gives a response of 200 with all the correct headers.

After the preflight, the GET request will happen and gives me the following response:

```
403 Forbidden
```

The browser will also give a CORS error, but I'm pretty sure that is because of the 403 response, as the 403 does not give all the correct CORS headers.

**Expected result:**

```
Status 200 OK
```

I try https://discord.com/api/channels/735303230694621228 with Postman with the same Bot token and it gives me a 200 response with the expected body.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting a 403 when I use axios with the browser on my local enviroment, but I get a 200 response with postman?

Comment: it seems that chatID variable is not actually being substituted.

Comment: use ticks ` instead of brackets `"` for the string assuming that you have a variable called `channellD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discord responds with a `403` for *some* `User-Agent`s on *some* API resources.

To test this, send a Postman request with your `User-Agent` header set to a value that matches a browser e.g `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`

Sadly, the browser will override the `User-Agent` header in an `axios.get()`, even if you define one in your `.get()`'s config.

The above is why Postman (`User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.0.0`) receives a `200` response, but your browser (`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`) receives a `403`.

---

It's worth noting that the Discord API documentation **does not** explain this (as at August 2020) https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue. In the end I used a proxy to change the user-agent header to something other than  (User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0)

Comment: @Charles How did you change the User-Agent...? I'm stuuuuuck

Comment: @Aastal you could point your `axios.get()` to the URL of an Nginx server with a `.conf` of something like...

`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://discord.com;
        proxy_set_header User-Agent 'Not-a-browser...honest';
    }
}`

Or use a similar technique with another web server (could be the server default configuration or a vhost configuration).